# How to Perform rightClick on an element using WebDriverIO?

Tags: webdriver-io, right-click

I tried  Keys and rightClick()  option.

Was getting ReferenceError: Key is not defined error with **await browser.keys([Key.shift,'F10'])**

and, seeing error TypeError: elem[prop] is not a function with  ** await this.pivotItem.rightClick()**

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

to perform right click, use await elementLocator.click({ button: 'right' })
you can also pass the number for key like [0, "left", 1, "middle", 2, "right"]

Here you can find the link for more details:
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/click/